# NavigationLink Button no action, no errors

Tags: swiftui

I have searched all around the web and I cant find a reason why it doesn't work.

I wrapped all my code on NavigationView {...code...}
And then wrapped my button inside NavigationLink with an existing View (Playground)

```
 NavigationLink(destination: Playground()){
                            A_Button(text:"Get Started")
                        }
```

My button struct

```
struct A_Button : View {

var text:String

var body: some View {
    Button(action:{}){
        Text(text)
            .frame(width: 290, height: 70)
            .background(Color("primaryColor"))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.title3)
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .shadow(radius: 5)
        
    }
}
```

}

Xcode doesn't bring up any error and doesn't make the transition.

Comment: Take a couple of SwiftUI tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

Solved

Adding inside the button NavigationLink:

```
                    Button(action:{}){
                                NavigationLink(destination: Playground()){
                                    Image("QR")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                }
                             
                            }
```

Comment: You could do this. Even easier, just use a normal `NavigationLink` and an `.onTapGesture` modifier.

Comment: A `NavigationLink` is essentially a specialized button. This code is redundant.